# "We can really capitalize on seeing many great teachers..."

Tags: sentence-meaning

What does it mean the following sentence? I could not understand  what meaning the part "seeing" adds?

> We can really capitalize on seeing many great teachers        share their areas of expertise,
> math, political science, for example, or religion, for us all to see.

Comment: I don't think it adds much meaning, but the whole quote sounds like extemporaneous speech, which is not always as careful or cogent as written material. Where is the quote from?

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Thank you for your comment. Since I do want to endorse any YouTube video here, I did not add its source but I can add if it is not against the rules.

Comment: You can add links. Since it's about a question, I don't think anyone will take that as an endorsement.

Comment: That's just a phrasal verb. Have a look into this link : https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/capitalize-on-something With this definition, you can easily get what the sentence means.